# Is there an api for javascript like there is for c#?

Tags: javascript, api

Anyone know of a full api that explains the javascript calls and methods? Like the ajax component?

Cheers,
Pete

Comment: an API is an automated program interface and does not explain anything. What exactly is your question?

Comment: "explains the javascript calls and methods?" Like... language specification/documentation? I don't think that "API" is the term you're looking for with a language.

Comment: Simon - Yes, by API I am referring to an Application Programming Interface (ive never even heard of an automated? PI) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Api, its basically a way for a programmer for to look at the interface to all methods and components of a programming  language/technology.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're after is the Document Object Model, or DOM, you can find an excellent reference at the Mozilla Developer Center here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM

This is often confused in terminology with a "JavaScript API"...you often don't want an API for a language...that wouldn't make much sense, you want what objects, properties, elements, etc are available to you when coding...like in your question, that would be the [XmlHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest) object.

Comment: I agree, and let me add that if you do a Google search for anything javascript related and add "MDC" you will get good results. Ex: search for `setTimeout MDC`

Answer (score 1):

Either you're barking up the wrong tree with the term "API" or you're looking for the [language specification.](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)

Note that "JavaScript" is the name for most implementations of the ECMAScript language standard (the map is not the territory). Not every implementation is the same, and maybe none implement the full standard. But we're close enough for horseshoes or hand-grenades, here.

Comment: "Note that ECMAScript is the standardized name for JavaScript" - that's not really an accurate statement, JavaScript means a few things depending on the context - for example are we talking about the language, or the Mozilla specification that's an implementation of ECMAScript?

Comment: JavaScript the implementation is really only in Mozilla based browsers. IE uses JScript, and Webkit uses a different flavor of ECMAScript. For example, lots of things in JS 1.7 https://developer.mozilla.org/en/new_in_javascript_1.7 are not available in non-Mozilla browsers.

Comment: @NickCraver, @sworoc -- how about the lengthier update? As I originally wrote it, I didn't like it. Should've known better....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about an api for javascript, but for javascript documentation go here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp

If you want to learn ajax, you should learn a javascript library like jQuery: jquery.com

Comment: Do *not* use w3schools as a reference, use w3c or Mozilla's Developer center, but *not* w3schools.

Comment: I would also recommend https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference

Comment: @Nick: I didn't find it __that__ awful. Guess I'll have to search for better resources.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a Javascript reference? If so, [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) has something like that. Otherwise, jQuery's [AJAX API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is what you perhaps need if you're going to use a framework.

Answer (score 0):

"Ajax" isn't really a part of Javascript, though it depends on your definition of Javascript. It's just provided by the host environment ( browser ). I would recommend these:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

The main language spec is at the [ecma site](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) but it's somewhat hard to grasp for beginners/non-programmers so I don't always recommend it.

There is also the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM), which is separate from Javascript. In the DOM the methods to modify/manipulate document elements are available so this allows you to add, remove, modify elements on an HTML webpage.